# add more custom post types and custom role to the code

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I want to add more post type and more role to the code below. The code is working great for single post type or role, any idea how to do that without breaking its function?

```
//Remove CSS custom post-types GRUP
add_action('admin_head', 'grup_custom_admin_post_css');
function grup_custom_admin_post_css() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      if ( $current_user->roles[0] === 'custom_role' )
    
    global $post_type;

    if ($post_type == 'custom_post_types') {
        echo "<style></style>";
                   
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This looks like a basic PHP question, does a variable have one of a list of values, e.g.  is the `$post_type` variable A or B or C or D etc, you don't need WP expertise to answer this, anybody with basic programming knowledge can solve the problem

Comment: apologize, newbie here and still learning :), do you have another approach for this case?

Answer (score 2):

its better to include your assets with `admin_enqueue_scripts`
for your question

```
add_action('admin_head', 'grup_custom_admin_post_css');
function grup_custom_admin_post_css()
{
    $allow_post_types = array('custom_role', 'custom_role_2', 'etc');
    $allow_roles = array('post_type', 'post_typ_2');

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (array_intersect($current_user->roles, $allow_roles)) { // do something if user have one of these roles
        global $post_type;

        if ($post_type && in_array($post_type, $allow_post_types)) {
            echo "<style></style>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great bro! although in this example something is reversed in the post-type array and roles. Any idea how to include my assets with admin_enqueue_scripts? thanks any way

Comment: @jasaweb its better to check docs. Shortly - attach function with `add_action`, action name `admin_enqueue_scripts` and add scripts and styles with `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`